# React CSS Modules - Some CSS is not applied (for 'active' class set by NavLink component)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The CSS for my `active class` does not seem to get applied on the rendered component, even though the rest of the CSS is actually applied. The CSS is applied using CSS modules. Since the `NavLink` component of react-router-dom package sets the class to active, I have selected the active class in the CSS file, but for some reason everything gets applied to the rendered HTML but that specific selection.

The `render()` *method* of the **React component**:

```
render () {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <nav className={CSSModule.Nav}>
                     <ul>
                         <li><NavLink to="/" exact>Home</NavLink></li>
                         <li><NavLink to={{
                             pathname: "/new-post",
                             hash: "#submit",
                             search: "?quick-submit"
                         }}>New Post</NavLink></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
            
            <Route 
                path={["/", "/home"]} 
                exact 
                component={Posts} />

            <Route 
                path="/new-post"
                exact 
                component={NewPost} />

            </Fragment>
        );
    }
```

The **CSS** code:

```
.Nav {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.Nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: burlywood;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Nav ul a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Nav ul a:active {
    color: white;
}

.Nav ul a:hover,
.Nav ul a.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lake-mgr0e?file=/src/styles.css) is a **codesandbox** sample.

After some more detailed research, it would seem like CSS Modules somehow block the styling for the active class from getting applied.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: @MajidM. added one right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should remove all `activeClassName="my-active"` in app.js
and add this in `styles.module.css`

```
a[class="active"] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

otherwise you should set `activeClassName={CSSModule.active}` for each `NavLink` and be sure that the `.active` is defined in your style

Comment: But why does it happen like this? Shouldn't .Nav ul a.active overwrite the color property due to the specificity of the CSS selector? Anyway, I have tried this approach and does not work. Please **check the codesandbox link** above.

Comment: This approach suggested by your updated answer did work on codesandbox, **but still did not work in my environment, even though it is now the exact same code**.

Comment: Maybe you should clear your cache, or maybe some other classes override this one.

Comment: I have updated the code on codesandbox to also include CSS modules, and this seems to be the problem. Having CSS Modules somehow block the styling for the active class from getting applied.

Comment: It DOES work now, thank you! Could you explain why?

Comment: I updated the answer, I added a second way that works without changing the styles.module.css.  Unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't recognize active element without these changes, while it recognize all other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your selector to `my-active` instead of `.active`:

```
.Nav ul a:hover,
.Nav ul a.my-active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: Please with inspect element of the browser check the `class` which has been given to the `a` element. Maybe its name has difference with `.my-active` because of `CSSModule`.